# Django ORM - No cascading deletion of a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm creating a Django application (using the out of the box ORM) to maintain pizza orders.  I have the following models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class PizzaPlace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)

class Order(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pizzaplace = models.ForeignKey(PizzaPlace)
    chef = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

I'm using a modelformset_factory to maintain each Pizza Place's employees.  What I want is regardless if an employee is fired or leaves a Pizza Place, the Order they fulfilled remains in tact and is available to the Pizza Place.  What is currently happening is when an Employee record is deleted from a Pizza Place, the delete is cascading.

What would be the best approach to maintain the association with preserving the Order - particularly maintain that the order was fulfilled, in the past, by the Employee who was deleted even though they are not associated with the Pizza place anymore?

Comment: Thanks Thomas and Enrico, you both gave me possible options.  After reviewing your responses and doing a little more research, I went with   "pizzaPlace.employees.remove(employee)" -- I realized that I actually did not want to "delete" the Employee record, rather just disassociate their entry with the PizzaPlace.

Answer (score 5):

You could:

- Not delete employees that are removed from a `PizzaPlace` and set a flag instead
- Use the `on_delete` argument to set the employee field to null: `chef = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)`

---

Look at the options for a `ForeignKey`'s `on_delete` in [the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) to find something that suits your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Clear the relationships before deleting the employees

```
e = Employee.objects.get(id=1)
e.order_set.clear()
e.delete()
```

I believe the order will still reference the deleted employee and you will have to deal with that, but deleting will no longer cascade delete all the orders.